# test round-robin in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

Context:
2 Nodes with 3 Pods

Node-1:Pod-A,Pod-B
Node-2:Pod-C

use NodePort to expose the service in my local virtual boxes(centos).

If I visit application by k8s service-clusterIP, I can see the round-robin is working among the 3 pods

If I visit application By Node-1, I didn't see the round-robin is working. only Pod-A is hit.

the round-robin is not working if access by Node IP? (the node have more than 1 pod)

---

10.144.39.* (company network)

192.168.*  k8s  network

**Env:**
Mac laptop
k8s cluster is hosted in the VM(3 instances:Master,Node-1,Node-2)

**k8s clusters**

Master

Node-1:Pod-A,Pod-B

Node-2:Pod-C

**IP info:**
Master 10.144.39.107

Node-1: 10.144.39.108  192.168.84.128

Node-2: 10.144.39.109  192.168.247.0

**Testcases:**

1.send request from Mac env

step:

```
wget -qO- http://10.144.39.108:1651 (node-2 with 2 pods)
```

Result:

Round-Robin:only hit the Pod-A

---

2.send reqeuset from the master/node-1/node-2 VM (Master server)

step:

```
wget -qO- http://10.144.39.108:1651 (node-2 with 2 pods)
```

Result:

Round-Robin: only hit the Pod-A,Pod-B

---

3.send request from the cluster inside:

steps:

1.kubectl exec busybox -it /bin/sh

2.wget -qO- http://10.144.39.108：31651

3.exit

Round-Robin:  hit the Pod-A,Pod-B,Pod-C

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you visit through `Node-2`, you only hit `Pod-C` then?

Comment: Also, what proxy-mode does your kube-proxy use? Is it in `iptables` mode?

Comment: visit through Node-2, hit Pod-A,Pod-B, but Pod-C

I used kubeadm to init the cluster, doesn't install the kube-proxy, any default mode for kubeadm init?